# How to install ROS on another partition not /opt

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install ROS on another partition because my / partition is almost full.

How do I install ROS on the partition I specify on parameters? like /dev/sdc5

I found a similar question but with no answer that tells how to change partitions.

http://answers.ros.org/question/211/diamondback-install-size

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10561/how-to-install-ros-on-another-partition-not-/opt/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you want to install from source or packages?

From packages, you can't really change the path of installation.
The cleanest way I would suggest is to mount your other partition at /opt (unless your already have other things in /opt, then mount it at /opt/ros). Then the installation would reside in /opt but on the other partition.
Alternately you can make a symlink to /opt/ros from your other partition.

From source you can choose any directory you want and then set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2